# jQuery save toggleClass in cookie or localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, local-storage

I am trying to save a cookie or use `localStorage` (whichever is better) to remember when a visitor has clicked on a plus button to show/hide a div. Can anyone assist in helping make the below code work with a cookie or `localStorage`?

```
$('.plus').on('click', function(e) {
    $(".plus .icon .two").toggleClass('horizontal');
    $(".welcome-section").toggleClass('open');
    $(".welcome-header p").toggleClass('explore');
});
```

Comment: I don't see any attempt to use a cookie.

Comment: I was trying to use if (element.hasClass("toggled")) {
     localStorage.setItem('toggled', 'true');
   } else {
     localStorage.setItem('toggled', 'false');
   } but all i was getting was errors and was getting in over my head. ugh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage):

**Javascript:**

```
var $content = $('.js-content');

if (localStorage.getItem('isVisible') === 'true') {
    $content.addClass('content_visible');
}

$('.js-button').on('click', function() {
    $content.toggleClass('content_visible');
    localStorage.setItem('isVisible', $content.hasClass('content_visible'));
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.content {
    display: none;
}

    .content_visible {
        display: block;
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<button type="button" class="js-button">+</button>
<div class="content js-content">This is content</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/cc5a3mcd/3/)

Comment: This is great if you only have 1 element that you need to remember the state of, but what if you have multitudes more. Any idea on how to build a loop that will dynamically create multiple keys to check?

Comment: @sergdenisov you are a savior. Thanks man it took me 3 hours to find this solution of yours but it worked like a charm. Thanks again